# High voltage high frequency transformer driving

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage

As I want to build SMPS circuit to produce high voltage output (about 4 kV). I was trying to build a circuit like this (not 555 but a 12V square wave to drive IGBT's gate). What I need to design is an arc producer about 4 kV (10 mA max) AC output from a DC supply of 300 V.

[image]

I was searching for solutions and I saw [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236092/how-to-properly-wind-a-high-frequency-high-voltage-transformer) topic. There was a term that says "**resetting the flux**".

1. What is the difference between these circuits. I am asking this because my circuit also won't swing between negative voltages to change flux direction. Do I need an H-bridge driver to drive this type of circuit?
2. Is there another topology that I can use? Can I use an ignition coil to do this?

Comment: You need to be much clearer about things. I answered the linked question so I'm probably going to make an answer but you need to state what you are trying to achieve because you may be going down the wrong path.

Comment: Ok editing question.

Comment: A 40 watt H bridge is probably going to be a better solution because flux resetting is done automatically but you need to wind your transformer carefully with adequate insulation between secondary layers to avoid flashover.

Comment: Do you think will it be suitable like in this link. [link](https://highvoltageforum.net/index.php?topic=390.0)

Comment: do you need a dc output or a pulsed output? i think you can use a flyback architecture, basically that is what you have in your schematic except for the missing diode and capacitor, on the other hand the transformer you would need is somewhat big, as the flyback transformer actually works as 2 coupled inductors, as @Andyaka says an h bridge could be suitable, and you would be able to use a smaller transformer, however given the high voltage and the required effort to wind something that doesn't flash over i wonder if its worth the effort to do so

Comment: @diegogmx I tried to use flyback topology but rectification and reflected voltages (snubber calculations etc)make things hard. So to simplify the circuit I decided to use high frequency pulsed output. But I will try dc output later for this project.

Comment: @Ismail those techniques for the secondary look good.

Comment: If DIY custom-wound transformer, then a center-tapped primary will reduce any core- saturation problems. (Search on "induction heater" projects using 2-mosfet oscillators.)  Not an option for automotive coils.   With this single-mosfet driver, make your duty-cycle adjustable, rather than 50%.  Then vary it it to find the max Vout on the secondary.